# How do I set PostgreSQL's application_name so that it doesn't get the "?" characters?

Tags: php, postgresql, unicode, iconv, transliteration

I have this UTF-8 string in PHP:

```
$test_title = 'My criticál business applicätiön';
```

If I send that to PostgreSQL to set the `application_name`, it then looks like this:

> My critic?l business applic?ti?n

Is there a way to include characters outside of ASCII in a PostgreSQL client’s `application_name`?

Comment: To @Ry-♦, your edits where unnecessary. We are presumably all adults here and can handle a rant without coming unglued. There where important points in the information you edited out, that are now lost.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: There really weren’t important points, and the rant, deleted, and edited comment parts were already unacceptable.

Answer (score 2):

Use ASCII characters. It is spelled out here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-APPLICATION-NAME

> Only printable ASCII characters may be used in the application_name value. Other characters will be replaced with question marks (?).

For a recent (ongoing) thread on this see:

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/MHDH6oj--3-2%40tutanota.com

It is point 1). Some of the follow up replies address this.

Comment: The question was "How do I set PostgreSQL's application_name so that it doesn't get the “?” characters?" and I gave you the answer and the link to the documentation that spells it out. You may not like the answer, but it does not make it any less correct.

Comment: To whomever deleted/edited the comments, that was not acceptable. People can openly disagree without others trying to sweep it under the rug.

Comment: I deleted comments for rudeness, not disagreement. The OP is free to choose better wording and try again. (Speaking of better wording, it’s “whoever”.)